# ckEditor and pediodic jQuery Ajax for multi editors

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I use inline edit feature of ckEditor and Ajax of jQuery (learnt from oleq) to illustrate the problem I have. It works fine if I just have one editor. The text is read from a file then by periodic ajax function text is written back to the file.
The following code shows that.

```
<?php
if (!is_file('textFile.txt')) {
    file_put_contents('textFile.txt', 'This is the contents of file textFile.txt');
}

if (count($_POST)) {
    //retrieve data from POST write to the file
    if (isset($_POST['textFile'])) {
        file_put_contents('textFile.txt', $_POST['textFile']);
    }
    exit;
}
?> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="./css/jQuery.js"></script>          
<script src="./ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
<script>
    // The "instanceCreated" event is fired for every editor
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(event) {
        var editor = event.editor,
            element = editor.element;
    });
</script>
<div id="container">
    <p id="text" contenteditable="true">
        <?php echo file_get_contents('textFile.txt'); ?>
    </p>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
        var editor = CKEDITOR.inline('text', { on: {
            instanceReady: function() {
                periodicText();
            }
        }});
        CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = false;

        var periodicText = (function() {
            var data, oldData;
            return function() {
                if ((data = editor.getData()) !== oldData) {
                    oldData = data;
                    console.log(data);
                    $.post("help.php", { 
                            textFile:data
                        }
                    );
                }
                setTimeout(periodicText, 1000);
            };
        })();
    </script>
</div>
```

### This second script I wrote for 2 editors and it does not work. Thanks in advance for telling me what did I do wrong. :)

```
<?php
    if (!is_file('textFile.txt')) {
        file_put_contents('textFile.txt', 'This is the contents of file textFile.txt');
    }
    if (!is_file('foxFile.txt')) {
        file_put_contents('foxFile.txt', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
    }

    if (count($_POST)) {
        //retrieve data from POST write to the file
        if (isset($_POST['textFile'])) {
            file_put_contents('textFile.txt', $_POST['textFile']);
        }
        if (isset($_POST['foxFile'])) {
            file_put_contents('foxFile.txt', $_POST['foxFile']);
        }
        exit;
    }
?> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery/jQuery.js"></script>          
<script src="./ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
<script>
    // The "instanceCreated" event is fired for every editor
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(event) {
        var editor = event.editor,
            element = editor.element;
    });
</script>
<div id="container">
    <p id="text" contenteditable="true">
        <?php echo file_get_contents('textFile.txt'); ?>
    </p>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
        var editor = CKEDITOR.inline('text', { on: {
            instanceReady: function() {
                periodicText();
            }
        }});
        CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = false; 

        var periodicText = (function() {
            var data, oldData;
            return function() {
                if ((data = editor.getData()) !== oldData) {
                    oldData = data;
                    console.log(data);
                    $.post("bar.php", { 
                            textFile:data
                        }
                    );
                }
                setTimeout(periodicText, 1000);
            };
        })();
    </script>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <p id="text" contenteditable="true">
        <?php echo file_get_contents('foxFile.txt'); ?>
    </p>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
        var editor = CKEDITOR.inline('text', { on: {
            instanceReady: function() {
                periodicFox();
            }
        }});
        CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = false; 

        var periodicFox = (function() {
            var data, oldData;
            return function() {
                if ((data = editor.getData()) !== oldData) {
                    oldData = data;
                    console.log(data);
                    $.post("bar.php", { 
                            foxFile:data
                        }
                    );
                }
                setTimeout(periodicFox, 1000);
            };
        })();
    </script>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] This version works though I did not put it in a loop for clarity.

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
var editor1 = CKEDITOR.inline('text', { on: {
    instanceReady: function() {
        periodic();
    }
}});
var editor2 = CKEDITOR.inline('fox', { on: {
    instanceReady: function() {
        periodic();
    }
}});

var periodic = (function() {
    var data, oldData;
    return function() {
        if ((data = editor1.getData()) !== oldData) {
            oldData = data;
            console.log(data);
            $.post("bar.php", { 
                    textFile:data
                }
            );
        }
        else if ((data = editor2.getData()) !== oldData) {
            oldData = data;
            console.log(data);
            $.post("bar.php", { 
                    foxFile:data
                }
            );
        }
        setTimeout(periodic, 1000);
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You've got incorrect HTML. No DTD, no `title` - you should add this at least. Otherwise browser/CKEditor may not work as expected.
2. You have to switch `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline` to `true` and leave it, because it has to be `true` when DOM loads (CKEditor looks then for editable elements). If you'd check console you'll know that errors are being thrown.
3. Then there's another issue - `periodicFox` variable will be shared between two editor instances and that will cause that after a while only second instance will be updating but two times more often. Wrap code initializing each of editors with closure.
4. It is rather a bad idea to send two separate AJAX requests to save both editors' contents. You may add one loop checking both instances and sending them in one request.
5. The rest of your code seems to work, although... check your sample page.

Comment: Thanks Reinmar! I revise the code per your advise. It works now. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a loop version ofthe pediodic jQuery Ajax for multi CKEditors.

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
var editor = [];
var id = ["foo", "bar"];

for (var i=0; i<id.length; i++) {
    editor[i] = CKEDITOR.inline(id[i], { on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            periodic();
        }
    }});
}

var periodic = (function() {
    var data;
    var oldData = [];
    return function() {
        for (var i=0; i<id.length; i++) {
            if ((data = id[0].getData()) !== oldData[i]) {
                oldData[i] = data;
                $.post("update.php", { 
                    id:id[0],
                    data:data
                });
                break;
            }
        }
        setTimeout(periodic, 1000);
    };
})();
```